# When using shutil.copy2() to copy __init__.py files, it fails. How do I copy __init__.py files?

Tags: shutil, copying

I have a tool that rolls out one main configuration across multiple configurations. It takes many files and folders (some are code files, some are not) and copies them to a new location, or updates a current location with a newer roll out.  This works perfectly, except one little thing.  The **shutil.copy2(s, d)** that I am currently using totally ignores __init__.py files.  Thus, when the new configuration runs, errors are thrown because all of the __init__.py files were ignored in the copy.
Due to the selective nature of this routine, I cannot always copy entire folder structures, because sometimes singe files, or random selections of files in random folders are being rolled out individually.
How can I get my python code to physically copy an empty (or otherwise) __init__.py file?
distutils or other distribution techniques are not what I'm looking for here.  I'm specifically trying to get **__init__.py** files to **copy**

Example of what I'm running into:
Simplified file tree:

```
Folder1
    Folder2
        other_file.yml
        data.json
        other_code.py
        __init__.py
    File1.py
    file2.txt
    file3.psd
    __init__.py
```

Pseudo code

```
files = os.walk(path)  # I'm clearly short-cutting this here for demonstration
for f in files:
    shutil.copy2(f, destination)
```

Results in the destination:

```
Folder1
    Folder2
        other_file.yml
        data.json
        other_code.py
    File1.py
    file2.txt
    file3.psd
```

As you can see, only the __init__.py files are missing.
Any takers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `os.walk` returns a tuple of three items. Your example won't work. There must be something you have done before `shutil.copy2()` that (accidently) excluded `__init__.py` from being copied. Try `shutil.copy2('Folder1/__init__.py', destination)`, it should work.

Comment: It does not.  My example was pseudo code for what is essentially this:<br>
shutil.copy2('folder1/__init__.py', destination)
It just doesn't actually copy those files.
Again, this tool works across all other files.  I've been using it for the better part of a year, but, after running it, I always have to manually go back and copy anything that had __init__.py files in it.

Comment: Sorry but I need more information. Can you make a minimal working code so I can reproduce your problem? I can not reproduce your problem based on current pseudo code.